# Run time error 1004 on Excel add-in: Unknown file path

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, add-in

Several computers use an add-in created by my own. However, there is one computer that causes an error message to pop-up whenever I run this add-in's code that saves the add-in workbook.

[image]

Translation:

Run time error '1004':
1.The file name or path does not exist
2.The file is being used by other program
3.The workbook you are trying to save has the same name of other workbook

I believe whats is causing this is the reason number 1. Since there is no file named '60E80500'. Note if I run the same code again the error message is shown with a diferente file name.

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()

    'Functions to change the add-in's worksheet
    setLoginCom (loginComTextBox)
    setPassCom (passComTextBox)


    'Close login form
    Unload Me

    'Save WorkBook add-in
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The add-in full path is:
C:ProgramFiles\Comdinheiro\Comdinheiro.xlam

I would like to know why Excel is using the following path:

C:ProgramFiles\Comdinheiro\60E80500

Besides this Error message the add-in works perfectly.

Comment: Are you trying to save the add-in itself?  I'm guessing you need save something other than `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following syntax:

```
myFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

I find with vba the more explicit you are the less likely you are to have errors